# volum component for flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is there a volume component for flex 4?
I'm looking for something similar to the volume button and slider in the youtube video player. Clicking on the speaker button will mute/un mute.

Is there a place to look for open source flex components?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a pre-built volume component, but it should be fairly simple to put one together yourself using a [`Slider`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d95.html) for the volume level and a [`Button`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d9f.html) for the mute/unmute.

As far as open source component libraries out there, there's:

- [flexlib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/)
- Sean the Flex Guy has an [article up with 35 different libraries worth checking out](http://seantheflexguy.com/blog/2008/05/24/36-new-cool-flex-and-as3-tools-libraries-and-components/).